# Recursive type inference works for object literal but not for class

Tags: typescript

Why type inference works with this case

```
const test = {
  value: 42,
  fn: () => test
};

const value = test.fn().fn().value; // typeof value is number
```

but not for this case

```
class Test {
  constructor(public readonly value: number, public readonly fn: () => Test) {}
}

const test2 = new Test(42, () => test2); // error: 'test2' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)

const value2 = test2.fn().fn().value; // typeof value2 is any
```

In my case I have different matchers and type inference works great for cases like this

```
const matcher1 = new OrMatcher(
  new AndMatcher(new Matcher("("), new Matcher(")")), 
  new Matcher("a")
);

const result1 = matcher1.tryMatch(); // typeof result1 is ["(", ")"] | "a" | null
```

but when I try to add recursion to this

```
const matcher2 = new OrMatcher(
  new AndMatcher(new Matcher("("), new ProxyMatcher(() => matcher2), new Matcher(")")), 
  new Matcher("a")
); // error 'matcher2' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)

const result2 = matcher2.tryMatch(); // expected to see typeof result2 as ["(", ..., ")"] | "a" | null; where ... means recursion alias to type itself, but got any
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFk5gQC2gHgBUA%20ZAbwChlkwoBPTbHACgEoAuZQ5AH2RACuAGyEBuCgF8KFMHQAOKRrmiF86UgF5k6ZBAAekEABMAzmiV4o%20UDGhdSAfi7JOAkAGsQAewDuIcbIK2ljKUCaq6Caa2mb6hqbIAIJQUHB0%20Bghlvhunr4gxI7kVMgA2gDSyKDI7hB0XjAxALqcFipqJhVNxOISLsi53n4B8iiEAnJCEIReAKogwF4gRLoGEMZmyanpg-mFyFqEpYIAtgBG0E3iFAhCcCZmbVbccesJJrSgAOakwCeTEBO6zAZkyTAIJGK1DkAjOQmACGQCCWHygAgQYC8UGYcigwAAblgUFAIHAjEshHQaHAoF8IGBOIRWMUSlISrQGFk2IzePxhEIodRkCSwAIoCA%20SJxNQpGzbvczAAFKBePSc8HPUiUaGw%20GI5EgVHozHY3EEonC0nkkCU5AwECcNgHUhg0JEYjM7VC1nSHVwhE0egWJ1e6gisUSsA4YAmAB09rYsY5wdY0uQsuk8oeyAA8lAnkRYmsNkkUmkMgXdn5CgAaZyHCZTGbzRbLJ7hQuFX7-KZA8CgguQr0w-36lG0Y1Y5ixmfASAnEyMkye33p1cjvWB9W4bnOPiCESCsP0iOSsQ%20uV3bOJYyDovxTZl9Ku7JVgrEOvcLTt1SEKLdgE%20xBcwsghLUSg3AMDSNDEpxnWM50BRcuGXFkZXXXUA2TLkOD3M8j0tUVxTPNMMxucdkBOUCoAARgOfgIB8XN82o5gShARiklvViOKYp5mAAIkE1g6144INWEgTWBE5B2M4-iBLgKSKFTcjDTAS0TGEMA6K0KiNRopMgxw0RkAAejMmhRgaTTtLomMyiEgS6ykgSml5RSBN5A8hEzCj9NCAAmeixLzfi5KYm8jH4sSFOE0TOOVVVt0sZgnQ0UgAssQKZNi1jXOkusIvE0JBKU1gVPEaCNJJLShDAYK9OowKjJSthTIs1YFAxCAjBoLxkBMCAUECCAbNq7TgvuRzBLreCXNYNyPKU7z%20VMnxLBQeDKNJQ1LQQMUTFbZA4HhabMSsoI5yGoQYCAA)

Comment: I don't know how to answer "why is this happening" authoritatively other than to point to GitHub issues like [ms/TS#45213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45213) where the TS team says that the compiler's depth-first recursive walk through the program's abstract syntax tree can sometimes hit circularities in places a human being wouldn't, and it's not easy to change the compiler to do something better.  ...

Comment: ...Generally speaking the advice they give is to break the loop with a type annotation somewhere, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrX75W). I know you don't want to do that, but I don't think there's anything better in general. Does that address your question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, problem is matcher real type can be quite massive to type it on variable declaration, that's why I wanted to be able to infer it from constructor

Comment: @jcalz can we substitute {a: number, b: Proxy, c: [number, Proxy]} via any typescript's mechanism into {a: number, b: ..., c: [number, ...]}? If yes, then we can wrap creating of last matcher and replace all Proxy types to outer type

Comment: @jcalz Sorry, I should have provided [real example](https://tsplay.dev/w6vOvw) at first place, this is what I'm trying to achieve on type level. I didn't include runtime implementation for this, but it works as expected with recursion, I just need some way to be able to type this :)

Comment: This is probably impossible as asked, unfortunately. There is no programmatic way to abstract over the "..." quickinfo display at the type level. See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoAEMN) for your options.  Either you manually annotate, where you explicitly write out the recursive type you care about, or you can use a helper function to do it for you but this cannot be truly recursive because the compiler will always see this as illegally circular. We can make the helper type give up at some arbitrary depth (say, 30), and this works more or less. ...

Comment: ...  If that fully addresses the question now I could write up an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah, I see now, I really like this idea to substitute type, thank you a lot for this solution! May I ask you last question - https://tsplay.dev/mArk1W this one is impossible to do via any way? To have truly recursive type. All we can do is to have only up to some depth(like 30)?

Comment: I will write up an answer to the question as asked when I get a chance. The point of these comments is to clarify the question post, not to discuss followup questions, which belong in their own posts.  (But as far as I know there isn't a general way to avoid circularity warnings on circular types that works in all circumstances; if you find a way, great; otherwise, a depth limiter is a reasonable workaround)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's inference involves a recursive depth-first search of a program's abstract syntax tree, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#45213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45213).  It is fairly easy to write code where this search detects a circularity and gives up with an error, especially in situations where you are intentionally writing circular types.

In such situations, it is my experience that such circularity warnings cannot consistently be avoided with some simple technique.  In *particular* cases you can sometimes avoid errors by carefully curating the types, often explicitly defining or annotating something that you'd rather see inferred.  Other times it cannot be avoided at all, but you may be able to write a non-circular approximation of your desired type by building in an arbitrary depth limit.

---

For example, given your `IMatcher<T>` interface and various `XXXMatcher<YYY>` classes, you could decide to manually define the recursive type you were hoping to infer:

```
type M2 = "a" | ["(", M2, ")"];
```

And then annotate your `matcher2` variable in terms of that type:

```
const matcher2: IMatcher<M2> = new OrMatcher(
  new AndMatcher(new Matcher("("), new ProxyMatcher(() => matcher2), new Matcher(")")),
  new Matcher("a")
); // okay
```

And then things will work:

```
const result2 = matcher2.tryMatch();
// const result2: M2 | null
if (result2 && typeof result2 !== "string") {
  const s = result2[1];
  if (s && typeof s !== "string") {
    const y = s[0];
    // const y: "("
  }
}
```

---

On the other hand, you could try to write a utility type that represents how your lazy initialization of `ProxyMatcher` ["ties the knot"](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot), and get the compiler to infer the recursive type.  This is what you wanted to do:

```
declare const Sigil: unique symbol;
type Sigil = typeof Sigil;
type ReplaceSigil<T, U = T> =
  T extends Sigil ? ReplaceSigil<U, U> : { [K in keyof T]: ReplaceSigil<T[K], U> }

function tieKnot<U>(cb: (self: () => IMatcher<Sigil>) => IMatcher<U>): IMatcher<ReplaceSigil<U>> {
  const ret = cb(() => ret as IMatcher<Sigil>);
  return ret as any
}
```

The idea is that you pass in a callback to `tieKnot()` that represents a function returning an `IMatcher<Sigil>` where `Sigil` is some opaque type you don't really want to use, and then return a recursified version of it where `Sigil` has been replaced with the desired end type.  The above definition compiles without error...

...but you can't really *use* it without hitting the same circular warnings:

```
const matcher3 = tieKnot(self => new OrMatcher(
  new AndMatcher(new Matcher("("), new ProxyMatcher(self), new Matcher(")")),
  new Matcher("a")
)); // error! 
//Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

It even sort of kind of works:

```
/* const matcher3: IMatcher<"a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | 
["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" |
  ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" |
   ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" |
    ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | 
    ["(", "a" | [any, any, any], 
    ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"],
   ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], 

")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"]>
*/

const result3 = matcher3.tryMatch();
if (result3 && typeof result3 !== "string") {
  const s = result3[1];
  if (s && typeof s !== "string") {
    const y = s[0];
    // const y: "("
  }
}
```

But this is not an obvious improvement over your original code.

---

Instead, we can define `ReplaceSigil` so that it gives up after some fixed recursion depth... say, 30:

```
type ReplaceSigil<T, U = T, D extends any[] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]> =
  D extends [any, ...infer R] ?
  T extends Sigil ? ReplaceSigil<U, U, R> :
  { [K in keyof T]: ReplaceSigil<T[K], U, R> }
  : any;
```

Every time `ReplaceSigil` refers to itself, it strips a `0` after that `D` tuple, until eventually it runs out and just returns `any`.

Now this works with no error:

```
const matcher3 = tieKnot(self => new OrMatcher(
  new AndMatcher(new Matcher("("), new ProxyMatcher(self), new Matcher(")")),
  new Matcher("a")
));
/* const matcher3: IMatcher<"a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | 
     ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | ["(", "a" | 
       ["(", any, ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"], ")"]>
*/

const result3 = matcher3.tryMatch();
if (result3 && typeof result3 !== "string") {
  const s = result3[1];
  if (s && typeof s !== "string") {
    const y = s[0];
    // const y: "("
  }
}
```

It's not *exactly* the type you're looking for, but it's pretty close.  And it's the best I can do without manually annotating the type.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFk5gQC2gHgBUA+ZAbwChlkwoBPTbHACgEoAuZQ5AH2RACuAGyEBuCgF8KFMHQAOKRrmiF86UgF5k6ZBAAekEABMAzmiV4o+UDGhdSAfi7JOAkAGsQAewDuIcbIK2ljKUCaq6Caa2mb6hqbIAIJQUHB0+Bghlvhunr4gxI7kVMgA2gDSyKDI7hB0XjAxALqcFipqJhVNxOISLsi53n4B8iiEAnJCEIReAKogwF4gRLoGEMZmyanpg-mFyFqEpYIAtgBG0E3iFAhCcCZmbVbccesJJrSgAOakwCeTEBO6zAZkyTAIJGK1DkAjOQmACGQCCWHygAgQYC8UGYcigwAAblgUFAIHAjEshHQaHAoF8IGBOIRWMUSlISrQGFk2IzePxhEIodRkCSwAIoCA+SJxNQpGzbvczAAFKBePSc8HPUiUaGw+GI5EgVHozHY3EEonC0nkkCU5AwECcNgHUhg0JEYjMyis6Q6uEImj0CxO7VCkViiVgHDAEwAOntbBjHKDrGlyFl0mk8oeyAA8lAnkRYmsNkkUmkMgXdn5ClqSjC-fqUbRjVjmDH28BICcTIyTJ6fWmB-W9QH1bhucgAEr08OEUaF44Cc6XUoAIiTWVX3V5ghEguoYfFkrE3rld2ziWMBcIRfimzL6Vd2SrBX2IeH-oNRoxrfbMc7gI9lwfYsjKQ66v6G5MBOTzhIWpB8LuAohgeM5HkhqbpjcTbICcWTQAAjAc-AQD4ub5vh2IlCApFJFelHMDRZFPMwq6sawAA0JHMQxq6sHxnHUbRLGrnAfEUCm2GGmAlomMIYBEVoeEagRiaBlyKbIAA9FpNCjA0snyUR0ZlGxq5cXxW68qJq47vyGYgHAQImHIiCKHAghwEIl7eGAWCLBKIaBIoABMxE2bya6sVx6AhRZ-FNCUX4ycpoQhZwT4ELF0RMeRLElNQuWXkYLG5SJ7FcblyqqmOljME6GikKllghZx3HBBq7ECRxBXtSJYmsCUknUMlhlCGAYVKZRIVqbVbCpjpSI4SScnjel2hhYh9nUMAjTMCt8lhQAZEdekKAZB1rcgACEGhaKuqLfHx+5LdJyBmFol0TaUBFXL1u3IMwZgnWdEAGWYt33Y9IBfM9KFCqNVJaJ0AAMf1CkKi2I5wZm9VIYFso5zmuUgyAAMJCF4JgQAAQgIYAAHJeGTwBfDSoHIEYEDyiSr0fMgADKrPAEIrgLAAjgIKAmHQ5xeCe1DBYLwsClowUGULXwi6mSvTpMbmayLRBcbMxGQhovUvMWCSGwKTh63cSC2-gswm6QnBkGUlTVLU9SNIQLRThA+tOyrRBdG7g4lDAbgYgFNDABA5S+S7xDMAgZyOtTQgwI6zKNeYlH4LbHrOoXGqpxw5dug7Bth7Mb69aNIrERn9X56QLf3NX2Ql8NoZoRKXdmB5dDeklOHNdAADMxFgInydeGAQMQDnZe5Xm+UY0V9GdWVvEVe11Vqix2cwG1++dZZrCCdvwm8QNQ2aYt0AqlA13ICUOlzkEoAfB589-JLCqEWJADwCSrypFzYOyAPJGGQHIKmJhgBwipDYUAAEYzMBCgAVgABwAE5BrUC0gAKj5ilSi08MoFginwKK5lkB0NMtFJhYlIpmQsuw+hnC2G2T4CUBhXD+EsMYcwoRfDeC9QkeI3hsjWHyLEdw0RwiOEKOUTIjRcjuG9RUZInh6iRGaKMdokxhi1FKLMZYixqieC6L0Yo2xDitHmIMdYtxTjjE2P0Z-DG1AvH0NHlxIJsCQB0CaFxexlkIlMISvFLc8SYnRMSSk2JCS0lJLiRk1JyTsnZPsXk3JRSsnFPSaUzJZSSlVPSQU8pOTqndBKKQrSA5m4QFWmAWeU0NTT1msmVMAN9rtPkrPEG6tGhfVnpDJh0NYb9gxqND6Y1Ok-XRkKQZwNTrjPejdO6MzPgwzhvYxGxFUZrIxljHCdAcasTxuPQmTl2kkxQAAEWDpGAAMn8AC8CQxcx5igUatsxbAEltLWWZx5Y61GMrLWqtQYaxVtcRWMLa6hzhcbZAptDhcReasO8oS6ClCaMRUoKMuLkuQJS6lFLaVUtpb1Gl9LmVMtZXStlLL2VcpZduC2GM8WvBLKUEJf4bB2EnCShwlt8VvDMLbZA9tg6OwgM7V2WKuKTndr1T2FQqgSl9gZAOnA0UqrDkccoMS1WasHBjTgo9kV2ljvPYB88k4pwbunTOgMz55zLplKwfc-UFgblXf1+ATWqsbgs5a9JW5nHbmXYePcCB91TKhUUR4k2j3HiNSeVC54L18ivNeBcN4UU6r1HeJUGKX1CKxQ+VUVQnwYmfC+98r78Rvj1O+PEr6P2oDfBa5DRpTygNQ5NVhHE+ICc4qxnjTHeOYQUmdK6F0eOnWu2di6XHuN8X4oUEiQl1MKQ0+plTz0VMvWeq9GTiBNJaRPN6kziKjt6VBcc-dBnPrGfpCZwzxpTL2Q9A5cyXqLOIpM1Zaaqh7U2QixoEMgOzKOfuk5yMyXnMxrpbGTDbkY3xlHCQQA)